# Nginx - Limit the max number of connections per file on nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to limit to `8` the max number of connections that a client can use to download a specified file and make able that he can download a second file even if the limit of connections of the first file is reached, this second file also have its limit of `8` connections. Those limits must be per IP and not global.

Here is an example that I tried but nginx does not allow two variables at the same time for `limit_conn_zone`:

```
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr$uri zone=peruri:10m;

server {
    ...
    limit_conn peruri 8;
}
```

Comment: You should consider upgrading your nginx. «Prior to version 1.7.6, a key could contain exactly one variable.»

Comment: Or you could use `map` directive to combine variables into one new variable